# Is DSP a branch of Computational Science?

Tags: soft-question

The way I understand it, computational science covers a wide range of fields, all of which use computers and mathematical models to solve a problem involving one of the sciences (physical, life etc.).

But is DSP, which does use maths to manipulate a signal, a form of computational science?

Comment: hell no! (says the electrical engineer)

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson why not? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Its not . Although , computational sciences covers very wide range of subjects but to be able to implement DSP , one must have a thorough understanding of signal fundamentals . That is not a part of computational sciences .

Answer (score -1):

DSP is a branch of electrical engineering, not science.

Comment: is *Computational Science* a form of science, or is **that** a branch of engineering?  "science" is about *discovery* (and *"systematizing"* the discoveries).  "engineering" is about *application* and *invention* (as well as "systematizing").  was DSP discovered or invented?  how about anything in Computer Science?  or in Computational Science?

Comment: Disagree with the EE bit. In the French education system, DSP is commonly taught as part of computer science curricula which do not include any EE class besides elementary logic gates - in specialization tracks such as multimedia systems, or numerical analysis - and the pre-requisites are mathematics (linear systems) and CS classes. I've taught in places in which the signal processing classes were under the supervision of applied mathematics or CS departments, or in which signal/stats/machine learning was bunched together in an entity separate from EE and CS departments.

Comment: That's weird, given that DSP is commonly done with FPGAs, which is rather closer to EE than CS.

Comment: Robert, I think computer science is a misnomer, but not one I spend any time fretting over. I'd rather get stuff done.

Comment: Not so weird... There are entire fields (say video coding, speech enhancement, biological signals acquisition, astrophysics data analysis) in which the algorithm design requires a much larger effort and a more mathematical/data-oriented set of skills than the actual hardware implementation - if there is any at all given how much stuff is now done by code running on general purpose computers or GPUs.

Comment: EE's develop algorithms too, you know :)